Proxy connection is ignored in webview
I'm trying to create a stable proxy connection in webview. Proxy is created. After 4 - 8 clicks on links inside the webview,
or after several loadings: webview.loadUrl(url1), webview.loadUrl(url2) ...
the connection through the proxy is ignored (webview start to load without a proxy).
private fun myproxy(proxy: String) {

    val proxyConfig = ProxyConfig.Builder()
        .addProxyRule(proxy)
        .addDirect().build()
    ProxyController.getInstance().setProxyOverride(proxyConfig, {
        //do nothing
    }, { })
}

...

myproxy(my_proxy_adress)

...

webview.loadUrl(url)  


Android Studio Koala
emulator - Pixel 8 API 34
I'm trying to think of something else.

I solved the problem:
private fun myproxy(proxy: String) {

ProxyController.getInstance().clearProxyOverride({},{})

  val proxyConfig = ProxyConfig.Builder()
    .addProxyRule(proxy)
    .addDirect().build()
  ProxyController.getInstance().setProxyOverride(proxyConfig, {
    //do nothing
  }, { })
}

